# How to access the instance from a model manager?

Tags: django, django-taggit, django-managers

I was told that doesn't make sense as managers operate on all rows not a single instance but I see what I want to achieve done in django-taggit library.

Here: https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/managers.py

And the the installation works as follows:

```
from django.db import models

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Food(models.Model):
    # ... fields here

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Then to tag anything, one can simply do the following:

```
apple.tags.add("red", "green", "fruit")
```

Note: `apple` not `Apple`.

Yet, when I try to do it myself, I get: `AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via MyModelName instances`!

My code:

```
from django.db import models


class TagManager(models.Manager):
    def add(self, *tags):
        print("Testing...")


class List(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    tags = TagManager()
```

Then I am trying to call the add method as follows:

```
l = List.objects.create(...)
l.tags.add(...)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: How did you construct this? Please post the *full* traceback together with the code that you run.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Done. Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot more going on here. Despite the name, [TaggableManager is actually a *field*](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/managers.py#L361), that emulates some of a many-to-many field. You can't do this with a manager.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Okay, that makes total sense. I understand the trick now! Thank you.